# What is this purple icon on top of the Monkey Buccaneer?

Tags: bloons-td-6

This icon appeared recently in Bloods TD 6 on the Monkey Buccaneer:

[image]

It seemed to appear after unlocking the last skill for the ship. Creating a new pirate ship, clicking on the existing one, upgrading to the final skill, etc. didn't make it disappear.

It also appears from main menu > monkeys view:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/btd6/comments/riiqu3/what_does_this_purple_icon_on_my_monkey_buccaneer/):

> Thats a paragon icon, it means that you could (with enough exp) unlock a paragon to said monkey

The [game Wiki](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Paragons) seems to confirm this.